# React native expo gives wrong URI when i use Image.resolveAssetSource

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get image URI using below code but it gives extra 'assets/' in the URI

`// Get a reference to the bundled asset and convert it to a tensor
    const image = require('./assets/cat.png');
    const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
    console.log(imageAssetPath);
    const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
    const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();`

what I got as a result is

`Object {
  "__packager_asset": true,
  "height": 624,
  "scale": 1,
  "uri":`enter code here`"http://192.168.1.101:19001/assets/assets/cat.pngplatform=ios&hash=21bed959dacf6460b46e00715acaca4?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false",
  "width": 940,
}`

is there any configuration that I need to update

I need to remove it from the URI